# How to assign and retrieve values from multi nested Hashmap in java?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have created a nested HashMap  as follows

```
Map<String,String> timeStamptoValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
Map<Map<String,String>,String> timeStampvaluesToStatistics = new HashMap<Map<String,String>, String>();
Map<Map<Map<String,String>,String>,Long> timeStampvaluesStatisticsTovalues = new HashMap<Map<Map<String,String>,String>,Long>();
timeStamptoValues .put("xyz","hello");
timeStampvaluesToStatistics.put(timeStamptoValues,"COUNT");
timeStampvaluesToStatistics.put(timeStamptoValues."MIN");
timeStampvaluesToStatistics.put(timeStamptoValues."MAX");
```

I am facing two problems

1. When I am inserting values to timeStampvaluesToStatistics to same key it will overwrite the values with the latest entry. So how shud I proceed? I have tried creating a List in place of String in timeStampvaluesToStatistics. But then I got stuck in the next part for adding values to each "COUNT" or "MAX" or "MIN"?
2. Now I want to put values to timeStampvaluesStatisticsTovalues based on "COUNT" or "MIN" or "MAX.

How should I proceed.?

Comment: If you want multiple values mapped to a single key, you have to use a List (or some other data structure) as the value, then put whatever you want into it.

Comment: Why don't you consider using String as key and Map as value?

Comment: But later I wanna retrieve the values based on the Map as key

Comment: I'm pretty sure you messed something up when designing these data structures. You should rethink that, and consider asking how to achieve the actual goal, and not how to handle the issues that come from these - probably inappropriate - solution attempts.

Answer (score 0):

To do a multimap (map of `X` to `Collection<Y>`) then you just do:

```
Map<X, List<Y>> (or Set<Y> or whatever).
```

When you come to add an element just query the existing value. If the list exists then add the value to it. If the list does not exist then create a new one, add the new value, then put the new list into the map.

Comment: My problem is to insert values to 'timeStampvaluesStatisticsTovalues' to this Map based on the values of the inner map `timeStampvaluesToStatistics`

Answer (score 0):

No sure if I understood the problem... but what if you use as Key a String/Long and as a value the Map?
This seems very... odd:

```
Map<Map<String,String>,String> timeStampvaluesToStatistics = new HashMap<Map<String,String>, String>();
Map<Map<Map<String,String>,String>,Long> timeStampvaluesStatisticsTovalues = new HashMap<Map<Map<String,String>,String>,Long>();
```

A map is like a dictionary, searching a word by its definition seems not correct to me.
In other words, I think your approach does not feel correct.